# Confusion about the word "orthogonal"

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

When we say that two dimensions are "orthogonal" to one-another, I understand we typically mean the data, in terms of these two dimensions, are uncorrelated. However, there's something that confuses me: say we take a set of two-dimensional data and perform a change-of-basis to two new dimensions (such as with factor analysis). If we say want the two new dimensions to be orthogonal, do we mean we want the data, when represented under the new basis, to be uncorrelated, or do we simply mean we want the new basis vectors to be perpendicular to one another (when represented in terms of the original basis)?

It seems to me that when we say that PCA results in orthogonal dimensions, we're talking about eliminating correlation in the data, but when we then talk about orthogonal rotation of the components, we're only talking about perpendicular axes (and are in fact re-introducing correlation).

Comment: Perpendicular is the term in geometry. It's still orthogonal. If the basis is orthogonal, then yes, the vectors are perpendicular by definition.